# SoftLayer API: How to get advanced monitoring and firewall in the account from order billingId

Tags: php, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

After ordering Advanced Monitoring - Premium package using SoftLayer API "`SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Monitoring_Package`"

and Firewall on Vlans with SoftLayer API "`SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Protection_Firewall_Dedicated`",

I can get the `SoftLayer_Billing_Item` id value from each order.

How can I retrieve the monitoring device and the firewall device that I ordered on the `SoftLayer_Account` using `Billing_Item` id ?

I looked up methods on `SoftLayer_Account`, there doesn't seem have direct methods to get monitoring or firewall.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The monitoring agents are in a bare metal server or a VSI to get the monitorings you need to call the getMonitoring Agents

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getMonitoringAgents
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getMonitoringAgents

The dedicated firewall is in the vlan you can get that calling the method
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/getFirewallInterfaces

there is no a method to get the objects using the billingItemId you need first get the objects, get its billingItemId and verify if this billingItem matches with the one you got before

Regards

Comment: Thanks Nelson.    The http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/getFirewallInterfaces returns a object of "SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Module_Context_Interface".   SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Module_Context_Interface doesn't have datatype of SoftLayer_Billing_Item,  or createDate.  For he the  SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Module_Context_Interface object I obtain through this API, how can I link it to my order ?  Will the API only allow a single SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Module_Context_Interface object on a vlan?

Comment: Another question is which SoftLayer API method will allow me to cancel the SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Module_Context_Interface, and SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent object one I order them ?  These two object doesn't seem has Softlayer_Billing_item associates with them.   I cannot use SoftLayer_Billing_Item->Cancelservice to cancel them.

Comment: Regarding the first question try this method instead http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/getNetworkVlanFirewall,

Comment: Regarding the second question the way to cancel a service or device is by cancelling the billing item.So you need to cancel the billing item. The objects allows you to manage the device, I the case of the monitor package its billing item is associated to the billingItem of the hardware or VSI where you ordered it. so you need to see the billing item of the vsi or hardware and see the children of the billigItem. You can use the following mask mask[billingItem[children]] If you still having troubles let me know to prepare a code example.

Comment: To cancel a billing item use the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request method

Comment: Thanks Nelson.  Another question I have is how I can cancel ssl certificate.

Comment: try http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Security_Certificate/deleteObject