# SoftLayer API: How to cancel Security_Certificate, Network_Firewall and Monitoring_agent objects

Tags: php, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I created ssl security certificate, dedicated Vlan Firewall and Advanced monitoring using SoftLayer API complex types:

```
SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Security_Certificate
SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Protection_Firewall_Dedicated
SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Monitoring_Package
```

I try to find SoftLayer API which allows me to cancel these objects once they're ordered.

I can obtain the:

```
SoftLayer_Security_Certificate,
SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Module_Context_Interface,
SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent object form SoftLayer_Account.
```

But there're no `SoftLayer_Billing_Item` data type on:

```
SoftLayer_Security_Certificate,
SoftLayer_Network_Firewall_Module_Context_Interface,
SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent.
```

That will not allow me to use SoftLayer_Billing_Item->cancelService() to cancel them.

Can somebody please point me how I can cancel SSL certificate, Firewall and monitoring agent using SoftLayer API ?  I'd be appreciated if you can provide PHP sample code them.

Comment: I got the answers through another question See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388803/softlayer-api-how-to-get-advanced-monitoring-and-firewall-in-the-account-from-o/34396502#34396502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For **SoftLayer_Security_Certificate**, you only need the identifier from this, you can retrieve the Security Certificates identifiers with the following method:

> Method: SoftLayer_Account::getSecurityCertificates
>   Link: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getSecurityCertificates

Then you can delete this, using **SoftLayer_Security_Certificate:deleteObject** method.

Here an example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Delete Security Certificate
 *
 * This script deletes a security certificate
 *
 * Important manual pages:
 * @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Security_Certificate/deleteObject
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/wiki/index.php/license>
 * @author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 */
require_once '\vendor\autoload.php';

/**
 * Your SoftLayer API username
 * @var string
 */
$username = "set me";

/**
 * Your SoftLayer API key
 * Generate one at: https://control.softlayer.com/account/users
 * @var string
 */
$apiKey = "set me";

/**
 * Define the security certificate identifier. You can retrieve the identifiers from them using
 * SoftLayer_Account::getSecurityCertificates
 * @var int
 * @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getSecurityCertificates
 */
$securityCertificateId = 14584;

// Create a SoftLayer API client object for "SoftLayer_Security_Certificate" service
$client = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Security_Certificate', null, $username, $apiKey);

// Set init parameters
$client -> setInitParameter($securityCertificateId);

try {
    $result = $client -> deleteObject();
    print_r($result);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Unable to delete Security Certificate " . $e -> getMessage();
}

?>
```

2. Regarding to **SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Protection_Firewall_Dedicated** objects that you have in your account, you can get all of them with their billingItems with the following Rest request:

   > ```
   > https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Search/advancedSearch?objectMask=mask[resource(SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall)[billingItem]]
   >
   > Method: Post
   >
   > {  
   >    "parameters":[  
   >       "_objectType:SoftLayer_Network_Vlan_Firewall _sort:[fullyQualifiedDomainName:asc]"
   >    ]
   > }
   > ```

Once you got the **billingItem** from Firewall Dedicated, you can delete it with the following php script:

```
<?php
/**
 * This script cancels the resource or service for a billing item
 *
 * Important manual pages:
 * @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelService
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/wiki/index.php/license>
 * @author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 */
require_once '\vendor\autoload.php';

/**
 * Your SoftLayer API username
 * @var string
 */
$username = "set me";

/**
 * Your SoftLayer API key
 * Generate one at: https://control.softlayer.com/account/users
 * @var string
 */
$apiKey = "set me";
$endPoint = "http://stable.application.qadal0501.softlayer.local/v3.1/sldn/soap/";
/**
 * Declare the billing item identifier from Network Protection Firewall Dedicated
 * @var int
 */
$billingItemId = 26382998;

// Create a SoftLayer API client object for "SoftLayer_Billing_Item" service
$client = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Billing_Item', null, $username, $apiKey, $endPoint);

// Set init parameters
$client -> setInitParameter($billingItemId);

try {
    $result = $client -> cancelService();
    print_r($result);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Unable to Cancel Service: " . $e -> getMessage();
}

?>
```

For **Monitoring package** objects, the following script will help to get the monitoring package for a virtual guest and its billing item:

```
<?php
/**
 * This script retrieves a billing item of "monitoring_package" category code from a virtual guest
 *
 * Important manual pages:
 * @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Item
 * @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getBillingItem
 * 
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/wiki/index.php/license>
 * @author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 */
require_once '\vendor\autoload.php';

/**
 * Your SoftLayer API username
 * @var string
 */
$username = "set me";

/**
 * Your SoftLayer API key
 * Generate one at: https://control.softlayer.com/account/users
 * @var string
 */
$apiKey = "set me";

// Declare the server identifier
$serverId = 14463961;

// Create a SoftLayer API client object for "SoftLayer_Account" service
$guestService = \SoftLayer\SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest', $serverId, $username, $apiKey);

// Declare an object mask to relational properties
$objectMask = "mask[activeAssociatedChildren]";
$guestService -> setObjectMask($objectMask);

try {
    $billingItems = $guestService -> getBillingItem();
    foreach($billingItems -> activeAssociatedChildren as $billingItem)
    {
        if($billingItem -> categoryCode == "monitoring_package")
        {
            print_r($billingItem);
        }
    }   
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Unable to get billing item: " . $e -> getMessage();
}

?>
```

Once you got the **billingItem** from Monitoring Package, you can cancel this with **SoftLayer_Billing_Item::cancelService**.

Php SoftLayer Client:
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-api-php-client

Comment: Thanks Ruber. Another question, I ordered  "100Mbps Hardware Firewall" on a device (virtual Guest or bare metal server), instead of on vlan,  using complex type SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Protection_Firewall.  How can I get a list of firewall on the device, can I use the same "Network_Vlan_Firewall"  object ?

Comment: Hello mnnmountain,

Try the following methods:

**1. For Virtual Guests:**
[SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getFirewallServiceComponent](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getFirewallServiceComponent)

**2. For Bare metals:**
[SoftLayer_Hardware::getFirewallServiceComponent](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/getFirewallServiceComponent)